SQL count max records in a group
I'm trying to count the max number of times a taskname of Claim Creation or Claim Creation Followup was created before an Incoming task is created. But if a claim has both a Claim Creation and a Claim Creation Followup then I only want to count Claim Creation Folloups.  In the example shown below, claimnumber = 123 has a max of 2 Claim Creation/Followups created before the next Incoming task on 03/28. I've tried using a window function but I'm not even coming close. I created a group for each section of tasks but am not sure how to proceed.
This is code to create the sample data:
DECLARE @t TABLE
           (
               claimnumber int,
               taskname varchar(100),
               completedate datetime,
               tasknumber int
           )

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES (123, 'Claim Creation', '01/01/2024', 455),
       (123, 'Incoming', '01/05/2024', 367),
       (123, 'Claim Creation Followup', '02/01/2024', 566),
       (123, 'Incoming', '02/02/2024', 367),
       (123, 'Claim Creation', '03/24/2024', 455),
       (123, 'Claim Creation Followup', '03/25/2024', 566),
       (123, 'Claim Creation Followup', '03/26/2024', 566),
       (123, 'Incoming', '03/28/2024', 367),
       (224, 'Claim Creation Followup', '02/02/2024', 566),
       (224, 'Claim Creation Followup', '02/25/2024', 566),
       (224, 'Incoming', '02/26/2024', 367)
  
SELECT * 
INTO #test
FROM @t

This provides the following output:



Claimnumber
TaskName
Completedate
Tasknumber




123
Claim Creation
01/01/2024
455


123
Incoming
01/05/2024
367


123
Claim Creation Followup
02/01/2024
566


123
Incoming
02/02/2024
367


123
Claim Creation
03/24/2024
455


123
Claim Creation Followup
03/25/2024
566


123
Claim Creation Followup
03/26/2024
566


123
Incoming
03/28/2024
367


224
Claim Creation Followup
02/02/2024
566


224
Claim Creation Followup
02/25/2024
566


224
Incoming
02/26/2024
367



The desired output should look something like this:



Claimnumber
TaskName
Completedate
Tasknumber
ClaimCount
MaxCount




123
Claim Creation
01/01/2024
455
1



123
Incoming
01/05/2024
367




123
Claim Creation Followup
02/01/2024
566
1



123
Incoming
02/02/2024
367




123
Claim Creation
03/24/2024
455
2
2


123
Claim Creation Followup
03/25/2024
566
2



123
Claim Creation Followup
03/26/2024
566
2



123
Incoming
03/28/2024
367




224
Claim Creation Followup
02/02/2024
566
2
2


224
Claim Creation Followup
02/25/2024
566
2



224
Incoming
02/26/2024
367





My attempt:
DECLARE @CreationTaskNum INT = 455;
DECLARE @FollowUpTaskNum INT = 566;
DECLARE @IncomingTaskNum INT = 367;

WITH SequencedTasks AS
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClaimNumber ORDER BY CompleteDate) AS Seq
    FROM 
        #test
),
Gaps AS 
(
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE 
            WHEN (Seq = 1 OR (TaskNumber in (@CreationTaskNum, @FollowUpTaskNum)
                  AND LAG(TaskNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY ClaimNumber ORDER BY Seq)
                 NOT IN (@CreationTaskNum, @FollowUpTaskNum)
                 )) 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0  
        END AS NewGroup
    FROM 
        SequencedTasks
)    
SELECT *
FROM gaps


I edited it to show my attempt.

Set rows  claim group (grn) -  all rows before 'Incoming' and row with next 'Incoming'.
So, we increase grn after row with 'Incoming'.
For this window function frame is rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding.
First row don't have preceding rows - use coalesce to get 0 instead null.
Then, we use grn value as partition (partition by claimnumber, grn ...) for count rows in group.
See example
select *
  ,max(claimcount)over(partition by claimnumber) MaxCount
from(
  select * 
     ,count(*)over(partition by claimnumber,grn)-1 claimcount
  from(
     select *
      ,coalesce(sum(case when taskname='Incoming' then 1 else 0 end)
             over(partition by claimnumber order by completedate
                  rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
       ),0)grn
     from #test
  )a
)b




claimnumber
taskname
completedate
tasknumber
grn
claimcount
MaxCount




123
Claim Creation
2024-01-01 00:00:00.000
455
0
1
3


123
Incoming
2024-01-05 00:00:00.000
367
0
1
3


123
Claim Creation Followup
2024-02-01 00:00:00.000
566
1
1
3


123
Incoming
2024-02-02 00:00:00.000
367
1
1
3


123
Claim Creation
2024-03-24 00:00:00.000
455
2
3
3


123
Claim Creation Followup
2024-03-25 00:00:00.000
566
2
3
3


123
Claim Creation Followup
2024-03-26 00:00:00.000
566
2
3
3


123
Incoming
2024-03-28 00:00:00.000
367
2
3
3


224
Claim Creation Followup
2024-02-02 00:00:00.000
566
0
2
2


224
Claim Creation Followup
2024-02-25 00:00:00.000
566
0
2
2


224
Incoming
2024-02-26 00:00:00.000
367
0
2
2



fiddle
Update1.
Your additional requirement do not require significantly change query.
Updated query
select claimnumber,taskname,completedate,tasknumber
  ,case when creationfollowupCount>0 then creationfollowupCount
   else claimcount 
   end claimcount
  ,max(case when creationfollowupCount>0 then creationfollowupCount
       else claimcount 
       end)over(partition by claimnumber) MaxCount
  ,grn,creationfollowupCount,claimcount
from(
  select * 
     ,count(*)over(partition by claimnumber,grn)-1 claimcount
     ,sum(case when taskname='Claim Creation Followup' then 1 else 0 end)
                over(partition by claimnumber,grn) creationfollowupCount
     ,sum(case when taskname='Claim Creation' then 1 else 0 end)
                over(partition by claimnumber,grn) creationCount
  from(
     select *
      ,coalesce(sum(case when taskname='Incoming' then 1 else 0 end)
             over(partition by claimnumber order by completedate
                  rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
       ),0)grn
     from #test
  )a
)b




claimnumber
taskname
completedate
tasknumber
claimcount
MaxCount
grn
creationfollowupCount
claimcount




123
Claim Creation
2024-01-01 00:00:00.000
455
1
2
0
0
1


123
Incoming
2024-01-05 00:00:00.000
367
1
2
0
0
1


123
Claim Creation Followup
2024-02-01 00:00:00.000
566
1
2
1
1
1


123
Incoming
2024-02-02 00:00:00.000
367
1
2
1
1
1


123
Claim Creation
2024-03-24 00:00:00.000
455
2
2
2
2
3


123
Claim Creation Followup
2024-03-25 00:00:00.000
566
2
2
2
2
3


123
Claim Creation Followup
2024-03-26 00:00:00.000
566
2
2
2
2
3


123
Incoming
2024-03-28 00:00:00.000
367
2
2
2
2
3


224
Claim Creation Followup
2024-02-02 00:00:00.000
566
2
2
0
2
2


224
Claim Creation Followup
2024-02-25 00:00:00.000
566
2
2
0
2
2


224
Incoming
2024-02-26 00:00:00.000
367
2
2
0
2
2



fiddle

The answer is great.  However, I had to make an update to the requirements.  If a claim has both a Claim Creation and Claim Creation Followup then only count the Followups.

Please add this requirements to question  and update desired output.

This is fantastic.  Thank you!
